# CollectionView Only refreshes on SVPullToRefresh, not on .reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to reload the data in my collectionView after calling a [URBMediaFocusViewController](https://github.com/u10int/URBMediaFocusViewController) 
and I cannot get my collectionView to reload no matter what I try. On dismissing the URB I call a custom class `func refreshAfterURB () {}` I have been trying loading so many different things in there to try and get a refresh but there has been no progress. When i print my collectionView using `println(self.collectionView?)` it returns `nil`. There should be no reason for this, so i tried doing a full refresh of my view controller using

```
func refreshAfterURB () {
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

But that doesn't refresh my collectionView,  it doesn't even reload the view i think because it maintains it's current scroll position but after that it will print the collectionView.

I need to be able to refresh my collectionView in this command or in a way like this.

The only way i have been successful has been with my SVPullToRefresh that i set up like this:

```
self.collectionView.addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler({
            println(self.collectionView?)
            self.refresh()
        }, position: SVPullToRefreshPosition.Bottom)
```

Knowing that works i tried the following, but no luck with this either.

```
    var instanceOfCustomObject: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.collectionView?.triggerPullToRefresh()
```

My CollectionView is set up like this:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

_

```
func setUpCollection () {

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2);
    layout.headerHeight = 0;
    layout.footerHeight = 0;
    layout.columnCount = numOfColums
    layout.minimumColumnSpacing = 2;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2;
    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = offWhite
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, screenSize.width, screenSize.height - 64)
    self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)


    self.collectionView.addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler({
            println(self.collectionView?)
            self.refresh()
        }, position: SVPullToRefreshPosition.Bottom)

}
```

So how do i refresh my collectionView in a function without having to swipe down to refresh?

Any further questions with my code feel free to ask.

***UPDATE:***

I added a few lines to find out;

1) Before i call reload data i print the new array count (60)

2) In the cellForItemAtIndexPath it only prints (30) for the count of the array

***UPDATE #2***

It was calling reload data before reading the plist

Comment: Where are those first four lines being called? From a method or a completion handler?

Comment: In my `refreshAfterURB()` i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It all came down to the fact that it was reloading the data before reading the data. In my case it was as simple as putting

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

at the end of my `readPlist()`

Anyone else in this situation i'd advise to print out the count of your array in several places to make sure it is filling up properly before reloading.